# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error creating form in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony1

I'm trying to create a forma on a symfony project but I'm getting this error on chrome (IE also returns error):

Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

I can't debug it, even using the dev mode it always return the same error.

How can I debug this error?!

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please provide the code of the controller action..

Comment: Could you post the error returning page or other information

Comment: The info above is the only info I have... suddenly it started working, I'm guessing it was a server config issue! Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: Did you ever sort out what the specific problem was? I have the exact same situation. Running locally in MAMP the problem doesn't occur however in our vagrant box, production environment and staging environments we get this useless error.

Comment: Sorry, can't remember...